Right side UI disappeared
The XYZ axis (gizmo), grab tool, and magnifying glass (and everything on the right side) disappeared after importing a model.

I don't know how importing a model did it, but your gizmos were disabled. The icon to re-enable them is the quarter circle with an arrow on the right side of the top bar.

The XYZ axis is a gizmo. It's in the upper right corner of the viewport. Here's the Blender manual for it
You could have disabled it with Ctrl+`
